# Moved a class to a different namespace, is it possible to add an implicit using to my files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring, resharper

I moved a class from one namespace to another, and now I have over 2000 errors to go through.

All the errors are related to the class that I moved, is it possible to implicitly or globally add a namespace to all my files somehow?

Or is the only way to manually go and fix each error?

I have ReSharper, but I am weary of making a global change and not even sure if Resharper go fix this ONE issue in all the files?

Comment: ReSharper can definitely rename a namespace for you.

Comment: Visual Studio can rename a namespace without Resharper, and update "using" references, but that will affect all the classes in that namespace, there's no easy way to extract a class into a new namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ReSharper you can right-click the class name, select Refactor from the popup menu and select Move... select Move Type To Another Namespace. ReSharper will change the namespace and correct all the files referencing the new namespace, an option if you can rollback your move.

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing the using statement on your classes that are calling this class?
If so, just use the search and replace for the entire solution from the old namespace to the new name. It will do it with. If they are in seperate projects in the same solution, you will have to add. a reference to that project.

Comment: there was no old using statement because it was in the same project, I moved it to another project so now I have to explicitly add the namespace, I did add a reference to the new project with the class, but I have to add a using statement to each file now and there are 2000+ errors.

Comment: Gotta love those .net tools.

Comment: This will not work if you are moving 1 of a number of classes in the namespace though.